Invoke-sqlCmd output CSV for each stored procedure results
I am trying to get multiple stored procedures, each out outputting certain results with varying column names.
I have managed to get the script to parse through each query however it just lumps all the results into one file. Is there anyway to have it generate the output (specifically via Export-CSV for formatting reasons) for each query in a separate file?
## DB Variables
    
    $ServerName = "vLonMhDb2012-1"
    $username = "sa"
    $passwordfile = "\\vlonmhapp2012-1\APX$\auto\Scripts\APXSA_PasswordSecurestring.txt"
    $SSPassword = cat $Passwordfile | convertto-securestring
    $PSCredential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username,$SSPassword                
    $DBPassword = $PSCredential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
    $DataBase = "APXFirm"
    $queries = @("set nocount on;EXEC [APXFirm].[APXUserCustom].[pReconPortfolioSFIM] @portfolios='@CUST_Recon_UBSLondon'",
    "set nocount on;EXEC [APXFirm].[APXUserCustom].[pReconSecuritySFIM] @Portfolios='@CUST_Recon_UBSLondon'",
    "set nocount on;EXEC [APXFirm].[APXUserCustom].[pReconAppraisalSFIM] @Portfolios='@CUST_Recon_UBSLondon', @DATE = '{yest}', @UseSettlementDate = 0, @AccruedInterestID = 3",
    "set nocount on;EXEC [APXFirm].[APXUserCustom].[pReconCashSFIM] @Portfolios='@CUST_Recon_UBSLondon', @DATE = '{yest}', @UseSettlementDate = 0, @AccruedInterestID = 3",
    "set nocount on;EXEC [APXFirm].[APXUserCustom].[pReconTransactionHistoryAOSEMEA_181] @IsFromDataLoad=1, @IsUseStoredAuditEventID=1, @PortfolioBaseCode='@CUST_Recon_UBSLondon', @UseSettleDate=0, @StartDate='{tdly}', @EndDate='{toda}'"

)
    ##------------------------------------------------------------------
    ## Run Stored Proc
    ##------------------------------------------------------------------

     foreach ($query in $queries)

{Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $ServerName -QueryTimeout 0 -Database $DataBase -Credential $PSCredential -Query $query -Verbose *>> "C:\temp\$CurrentTime.txt"}

So far only using -verbose *>> do i actually get the results from all stored procedures but of course they are lumped into one text file.
I have tried {Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $ServerName -QueryTimeout 0 -Database $DataBase -Credential $PSCredential -Query $query  | Export-Csv ($Outputpath + $CurrentTime + ".csv")}
But I believe output does not go to pipeline in a foreach loop so that's a no go.
Any ideas would be most welcome.

How are you setting the value of the $CurrentTime variable? That's not a magic keyword in PowerShell so it just holds whatever fixed value you assigned to it. Unless you update it in every iteration of the for loop it'll just contain the same value each time though the loop and write to the same file as a result...

Oh i'm sorry for that, this is not the full script i did not include any variables that i deemed irrelevant. Figured it out in the end. I just piped every query result into a variable and then had the export-csv piped to the variable. So for each query it would export a csv with the result to the directory needed.

In the end piping every query result to a variable and then export-csv piped from that variable result does the intended of creating a csv with each query's output.
     foreach ($query in $queries) {
     
       $returnresults = Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $ServerName - QueryTimeout 0 -Database $DataBase -Credential $PSCredential -Query $query

       $returnresults | Export-Csv ($Outputpath + $query.Substring(47,14) + "_" + $CurrentDate + "_" + $CurrentTime + ".csv")

     }

